# How can I set a column to be a random number between 0 and 2147483647

Tags: sql-server

I already have this code that I think I can use:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET FieldName = ROUND(RAND()*2147483647,0)
```

- If my field data type was INT then how could I ensure this generated a random number between 0 and the max of INT.
- Same for a BIGINT.  How could I ensure it generated and is it even possible to get a value between 0 and the max of BIGINT?

**Update**

Thanks BlorgBeard for the correction you suggested in your answer.

Comment: Your code sets `FieldName` to be a random number between 0 and the current value of `FieldName`. You want something like `= round(rand() * 2147483647, 0)`

Comment: @Blorgbeard - Thanks.  What about for a BIGINT? Would the same apply for that ?

Comment: For `bigint`, `= round(rand() * 9223372036854775807, 0)`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - Please add your comments in an answer so I can accept.  Note that I am going to open up another question related to this as I found a new problem.  Thanks

Comment: This will update all rows with the same number. If you want your number to be different for each row, you need to specify a different seed for each row. so instead of `RAND()` use `RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())`.

Answer (score 0):

To update the column with a random BIGINT number,

```
UPDATE TableName
        SET FieldName = ROUND(RAND()*POWER(2e0,63)-1,0)
```

OR

```
UPDATE TableName
    SET FieldName = Convert(BIGINT, ROUND(RAND()*POWER(2e0,63)-1,0))
```